# How to fetch customer user name and password from Magento DB

Tags: magento

I have Magento Database, I want to grab customer username and password from Magento Database using Mysql Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer do login with email and password and if you want all customers email and password then this query can help

```
SELECT c.entity_id,c.email, 
        (
        SELECT fn.value
        FROM customer_entity_varchar fn
        WHERE c.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
         fn.attribute_id = 12) AS password_hash, 

         (
        SELECT fn.value
        FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
        WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
         fn.attribute_id = 30) AS cep
        FROM customer_entity AS c
        LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity AS ca ON c.entity_id = ca.parent_id
        LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_text AS cat ON cat.entity_id = ca.entity_id                

        GROUP BY entity_id
```